# comparar e somar em sequencia com sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, servidor

através de uma tabela pretendo somar os campos da col3 verifando se o valor da col2 é igual ao seguinte, fazendo um group by sequencial.

```
col1 col2 col3
ind  seq1   5
ind  seq1   3
ind  seq1   7
ind  seq1   4
ind  seq2   5
ind  seq3   1
ind  seq3   3
ind  seq4   9
ind  seq5   6
ind  seq1   7
```

e preciso que o resultado fique assim:

```
col1 col2 col3
ind  seq1   19
ind  seq2   5
ind  seq3   4
ind  seq4   9
ind  seq5   6
ind  seq1   7
```

Comment: Com um select não dá. A menos que tenha uma coluna que defina como devem ser agrupadas essas somas.

Comment: Tente resolver usando cursor.

Comment: Dá pra fazer um cambalacho abusando `ROW_NUMBER()` e CTEs, mas pra isso você teria que definir uma coluna com a ordem "canônica" das linhas, já que `ROW_NUMBER()` exige uma cláusula `OVER` (que, por sua vez, exige uma cláusula `ORDER BY`)...

Comment: @Pedro, qual é a versão e edição do SQL Server?

Comment: @JoséDiz, é a 2008

Answer (score 1):

***FORMA 1:***

A seguinte `query`:

```
-- Gera uma coluna "sequencia" para ser utilizada de referência
WITH referencia AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS sequencia,
         t.*
    FROM tabela t
),
-- Calcula a coluna "agrupamento"
agrupamento AS (
  -- Pega o primeiro para definir como "agrupamento" = 1
  SELECT ref.*,
         1 AS agrupamento  
    FROM referencia ref
   WHERE ref.sequencia = 1
  UNION ALL
  -- Pega os subsequentes e apenas adiciona 1 ao agrupamento anterior se tiver mudado a "col2"
  SELECT atu.*,
         CASE atu.col2
           WHEN ant.col2 THEN ant.agrupamento
           ELSE ant.agrupamento + 1
         END AS agrupamento
    FROM agrupamento ant
         INNER JOIN referencia atu ON atu.sequencia = ant.sequencia + 1
)
-- Agrupa e soma os resultados
SELECT agr.col1,
       agr.col2,
       SUM(agr.col3) AS col3
  FROM agrupamento agr
 GROUP BY agr.agrupamento,
          agr.col1,
          agr.col2
```

- Utiliza `WITH` para criar uma tabela semelhante a de referência porém utilizando `ROW_NUMBER` para gerar a coluna `sequencia`;
- Calcula o agrupamento utilizando primeiro o registro com `sequencia` 1 para definir a coluna `agrupamento` como 0 como ancoragem;
- Pega os registros subsequentes adicionando 1 à coluna `agrupamento` caso mude de valor na `col2`;
- Realiza o `SUM` com os registros gerados e devidamente organizados.

**Observação:** Caso exista alguma coluna não informada que possa ser utilizada para ordenação, apenas substitua no lugar do `(SELECT 0)` no `ORDER BY` do `ROW_NUMBER`.

---

***FORMA 2*:**

Utilize um `cursor` iterar a tabela e calcular os valores colocando-os em uma tabela variável:

```
DECLARE @resultado TABLE(sequencia INT IDENTITY,
                         col1      VARCHAR(10),
                         col2      VARCHAR(10),
                         col3      INT);

DECLARE @col1             VARCHAR(10),
        @col2             VARCHAR(10),
        @col3             INT,
        @ultima_sequencia INT,
        @ultimo_col1      VARCHAR(10),
        @ultimo_col2      VARCHAR(10);

-- Percorre os registros da tarefa
DECLARE cursor_agrupamento CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT t.col1,
         t.col2,
         t.col3
    FROM tabela t;
OPEN cursor_agrupamento
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_agrupamento INTO @col1,
                                        @col2,
                                        @col3
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  -- Caso não seja o mesmo "col1" ou não seja o mesmo "col2" do registro anterior insere um novo registro
  IF @col1 <> ISNULL(@ultimo_col1, 0) OR @col2 <> ISNULL(@ultimo_col2, 0)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @resultado(col1, col2, col3)
                    VALUES(@col1, @col2, @col3);

    -- Guarda o último "IDENTITY" inserido
    SET @ultima_sequencia = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    -- Atualiza o valor somando o valor do atual
    UPDATE r
       SET r.col3 = r.col3 + @col3
      FROM @resultado r
     WHERE r.sequencia = @ultima_sequencia;
  END;

  -- Atualiza os valores que serão verificados na próxima interação
  SET @ultimo_col1 = @col1;
  SET @ultimo_col2 = @col2;

  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_agrupamento INTO @col1,
                                          @col2,
                                          @col3
END;
CLOSE cursor_agrupamento;
DEALLOCATE cursor_agrupamento;

SELECT r.col1,
       r.col2,
       r.col3
  FROM @resultado r
 ORDER BY r.sequencia;
```

---

> [**`WITH`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Uma CTE (expressão de tabela comum) fornece a significativa vantagem de ser capaz de se autorreferenciar, criando, portanto uma CTE recursiva. Uma CTE recursiva é aquela em que uma CTE inicial é executada repetidamente para retornar subconjuntos de dados até que o resultado completo seja obtido.

---

> [**`GROUP BY`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Agrupa um conjunto de linhas selecionadas em um conjunto de linhas de resumo pelos valores de uma ou mais colunas ou expressões no `SQL Server 2014`. Uma linha é retornada para cada grupo. As funções de agregação na lista de `<seleção>` da cláusula `SELECT` fornecem informações sobre cada grupo em vez de linhas individuais.

---

> [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, iniciando em 1 para a primeira linha de cada partição.

---

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5607e/9).