# Somar valores da linha anterior com a próxima

Tags: sql

Eu gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de somar os valores de uma linha com a sua anterior.

**Ex: No select abaixo, o resultado que estou obtendo não está fazendo o acumulado**

```
**SELECT DATMOV, VLRMOV, DEBCRE,
(CASE WHEN E600MCC.DEBCRE = 'C' THEN (VLRMOV) ELSE (VLRMOV * -1) END) AS RESULT 
FROM E600MCC
GROUP BY  DATMOV, VLRMOV, DEBCRE, E600MCC.SEQMOV, E600MCC.DEBCRE
ORDER BY  DATMOV ASC**

- DatMov                         VlrMov     DebCre    Acumulado
- 20 13-11-01 00:00:00.000        15          C          15
- 2013-11-01 00:00:00.000         10          C          10
2013-11-01 00:00:00.000         -5          D          -5
2013-11-01 00:00:00.000         12          C          12
2013-11-04 00:00:00.000        -20          D          -20
2013-11-04 00:00:00.000         50          C          50
```

Eu queria que a coluna acumulado fosse sempre a soma do valor atual com a anterior.

Comment: Qual o sentido deste GROUP BY? Pesquise por Window Function em seu SGBD.

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/585630-somar-valores-da-linha-anterior-com-a-pr%C3%B3xima/?do=findComment&comment=2285794

Comment: Relacionada: [**comparar e somar em sequencia com sql server**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190894/comparar-e-somar-em-sequencia-com-sql-server/241111#241111).

Comment: Você não informou o `SGBD`.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar as funções de janelamento (window functions) para fazer uma soma cumulativa. Elas estão disponíveis no SQL Server a partir da versão 2012. Para fazer com uma versão anterior, terá um pouco mais de trabalho.

A sintaxe de uma soma cumulativa é a seguinte:
SUM(expressão) OVER (cláusulas de ordenação e limites da soma)

O GROUP BY também não parece necessário.
Então seu SQL ficaria:

```
SELECT DATMOV, VLRMOV, DEBCRE,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DEBCRE = 'C' THEN VLRMOV ELSE -VLRMOV END)
    OVER(ORDER BY DATMOV ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) [RESULT]
FROM E600MCC
ORDER BY DATMOV
```

A sintaxe é meio feia, devido às opções de janelamento que precisam ser especificadas.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/SQL-Server-Cumulative-Sum-b1c40b0d